# Sequential ENUMs in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to create a sequential list of enum values in MongoDB, and more specifically MongooseJS?

What I mean is, for example, storing iPhone model like:

```
"model": {
    "type": "string",
    "enum": ["Original", "3g", "3gs", "4", "4s", "5", "5s", "6", "6s", "5SE", "7"]
}
```

or child clothing sizes:

```
"size": {
    "type": "string",
    "enum": ["3MO", "6MO", "9MO", "12MO", "18MO", "2T", "2", "3T"...]
}
```

and then use query operators like `$gt` and `$lt` to query for iPhones with

```
"model": { "$gte": "3g" }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can create enum in mongoose.

refer the the documentation here. it has detailed example.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_string_SchemaString-enum

Comment: Yes, I know you can create enums. But my question was about creating them as a sequence so I can use $gt and $lt in queries of them.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use `$lte`, `$gte` for string, it's only for numbers, but you still can query using `$in` operator

Schema

```
"field": {
    "type": "string",
    "enum": ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

Query

```
myModel.find({
    field: {
        $in: ['a', 'some other prop']
    }
})
```

This will find all instances that match `['a', 'some other prop']` in array

Comment: I understand. What I'm looking to do is map those strings to numerical values so I CAN use $gt and $lt and, for example, query iPhones where the model is greater than the "4s". I can do this outside the database schema, just using numbers in the database and map those to strings somewhere else, but I'd rather not obfuscate the data like that. Is there no built in mechanism for this?